# How do I resolve IDA pro Hexrays aliased local variables?

Tags: ida, hexrays

It appears to me that in my function the compiler has reused a stack slot for two variables of types. However, Hex-Rays has not recognized it as such. How can I split the local variable into two?

Comment: I think it depends on the exact situation, can you post an example?

Comment: @WillemHengeveld it's a pretty long function, but here:  https://gist.github.com/Zhentar/d65a0bbdcd489719cbec7b0b00761f85 
a3a, a4a, time, and time_1 are ones that I've noticed that seem to be aliased

Comment: I usually add structs with unions to make the output slightly more readable when the compiler has reused a stack slot for different variables.

Comment: @LéoLam you should post that as an answer so I can accept it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually add structs with unions to make the output slightly more readable when the compiler has reused a stack slot for different variables.

In 7.2, it seems that you can force the decompiler to ["create a new variable"](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/7.2/), which makes this easier and less ugly. Yay!

Comment: is that supposed to work in IDA Free 8.2?