# IDA Pro "force new variable" for register variable?

Tags: ida

IDA Pro 7.2 has a new functionality named `force new variable`.
See:
[Here](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/18365/how-do-i-resolve-ida-pro-hexrays-aliased-local-variables) and [Here](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/decompiler/manual/cmd_force_lvar.shtml).

But it is only efficient for stack-based variables. How can I force a new variable for a register-based variables?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't, not as a standard command that's currently available through the user interface, anyway. Force new variable only works for stack locations. Perhaps a future version of Hex-Rays will allow the user to force new register variables.